# One dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to know what the geometric interpretation of one and two dimensional subspaces of the vector space $\mathbb R^3$. In a mcq question, it is asked about one dimensional subspace of the vector space $\mathbb R^3$. It has given a straight line and a straight line passing through origin. Only one option is correct.

Comment: Why are you confused? Did you try out some examples?

Comment: It must pass through the origin, because the $0$ vector belongs to every subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that in order to preserve linearity, by definition, any subspace must contain the zero vector, therefore the one dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ is always a straight line passing through origin.

Comment: I'm confused because a straight line passing through origin is a straight line also. It seems two options are correct simultaneously.

Comment: @Noname A straight line doesn't pass necesserarly through the origin, as for example $y=x+1$ in $\mathbb R^2$.